# StreamWrite unable to write textbox.Text into a .txt file (Vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, file, text

I've been searching and trying multiple solutions for this problem i've ran into. I'm trying to save the results of a textbox as a line of text in a .txt file.

Here is the code before, when, and after i try to call upon StreamWriter to do this.

```
    If inttAnswer = vbOK Then
                totalprofiles.Write(filename & vbNewLine) '*this is not working*
                txtProfileName.Text = ""
                Me.Hide()
                Profiles.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
                Profiles.Location = Me.Location
                Profiles.Show()
    End If
```

Here are any declarations that i'm using for this section of code, which is part of a block of code that occurs upon a button press:

```
    Dim totalprofiles2 As String = "C:\SameSens\Profiles\TotalProfiles.txt"
    Dim totalprofiles As New System.IO.StreamWriter(totalprofiles2, True)

    Dim inttAnswer As Integer
    Dim filename As String = txtProfileName.Text
```

Thanks for your help.
If this is not possible, perhaps you could suggest a different/better alternative to being able to populate a ComboBox with the text in txtProfileName.Text permanently as an item once this particular button is pressed. I thought populating the ComboBox with a .txt files contents would be the easiest and most practical way, but its proving more difficult then I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
File.WriteAllText("c:\textfile.txt", TextBox1.Text)
```

But put a reference to;

```
Imports System.IO
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to the file once, then do this:

```
Dim path As String = "PathToYourFile.txt"
Dim sw As StreamWriter

If File.Exists(path) = False Then 
    ' Create a file to write to.
    sw = File.CreateText(path)

    sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)

    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
End If
```

If you want to keep appending to a file and have it grow over time, then do this:

```
Dim path As String = "PathToYourFile.txt"
Dim sw As StreamWriter

If File.Exists(path) Then 
    ' Append text to file, adding new text to the end of the file
    sw = File.AppendText(path)

    sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)

    sw.Flush()
    sw.Close()
End If
```

Note: It is recommended that you use the `Using` block statement (I omitted it, because I was not sure if you knew what it was and did not want to cause confusion), which will automatically close the `StreamWriter` object, even if an error occurs, like this:

```
' Create a file to write to.
Using sw = File.CreateText(path)
    sw.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)

    sw.Flush()
End Using
```

As you can see it makes the code simpler and eliminates the worry of cleaning up the `StreamWriter` object.

Comment: Please don’t write `= True`.

Comment: @minitech - I have removed `= True`, it was done on purpose, because I wanted to clearly show the opposing logic, but I understand your point.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip about "Using".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was able to fix this problem very easily. Tells me again I shouldn't stay up late coding :/

All I had to do was add the line:

```
    totalprofiles.Close()
```

Directly after initiating the StreamWriter. Otherwise it just didn't seem to want to write anything, no matter what it was originating from.

Thanks very much to both people who helped, it taught me about the usefulness of the "Using" statement, and I'll definitely try to incorporate that into my program.